# JavaScript how to use event.waitUntil() to wait for an async function call

Tags: javascript, async-await, progressive-web-apps

When learning about JavaScript it recommends using `async`/`await` as it's much more readable than `.then`, and I agree. Unfortunately when it comes to PWA service workers, `async` seems to be forgotten.

When trying to create an install function for a service worker with async style:

```js
const cacheVersion = "v1";
const cacheAssets = [
    "/",
    "/index.html",
    "/static/img/logo.svg",
];

async function install(version, assets) {
    const cache = await caches.open(version);
    console.log("Doing stuff....");
}

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
    console.log("Service Worker INSTALL START");
    event.waitUntil(install, cacheVersion, cacheAssets); // <--- Does not call install()
    console.log("Service Worker INSTALL COMPLETE");
});
```

The `install` function is never run. If I change this line:

```js
event.waitUntil(install, cacheVersion, cacheAssets);
```

to

```js
install(cacheVersion, cacheAssets);
```

Then the line is run, but not waited for, causing problems.

How does one use `event.waitUntil` to call an async function and wait for it?

To me `event.waitUntil` is like `await`, so why have this weird special function that blocks the main loop, when it seems like nothing else in JS does? Just seems so strange to me.

Comment: Side note: I haven't played with service workers nearly enough, but I'm 99.9% sure your final `console.log` will say the worker is installed prematurely. I suggest putting that call at the end of `install`, rather than after the `waitUntil` call. `waitUntil` just tells the event subsystem that the work is ongoing. I very much doubt it blocks the thread. (But again, I haven't played with service workers enough yet.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`install` isn't called because you don't call it. [`waitUntil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil) accepts a **promise**, not a function. An `async` function isn't a promise, it's a function that *returns* a promise.

Call your function and pass the promise it returns into `waitUntil`:

```
event.waitUntil(install(cacheVersion, cacheAssets));
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

Comment: Brilliant, I always thought async functions were a bit like Promises, I finally see the relationship, thanks.

Comment: @run_the_race - Glad that helped! FWIW, I go into promises and `async` functions in detail in Chapters 8 and 9 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested. Happy coding!